# Как создать коллекцию из своих объектов и переопределить метод сравнивания?

Tags: c#

В общем, есть класс Obj, нужно создать коллекцию объектов Obj и переопределить метод сравнивания объектов. Ибо могут добавляться дубликаты и сравнивать надо по конкретными атрибутами (atr1, atr2), а не по всем. (желательно)
P.S. пока что пользовался Obj[] array, но нужно решить проблему дубликатов. (да, в гугле все есть)

Comment: @VladD, ты хотел сказать `IEquatable`?

Comment: @Grundy: Ага, именно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь подойдет коллекция [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), которой в конструктор можно передать [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359100(v=vs.110).aspx) в котором можно определить правила сравнения объектов нужного типа.

[Пример реализации `IEqualityComparer<T>` из MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class BoxEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Box>
{
    public bool Equals(Box b1, Box b2)
    {
        if (b2 == null && b1 == null)
           return true;
        else if (b1 == null | b2 == null)
           return false;
        else if(b1.Height == b2.Height & b1.Length == b2.Length
                            & b1.Width == b2.Width)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Box bx)
    {
        int hCode = bx.Height ^ bx.Length ^ bx.Width;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

И при создании коллекции:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet(new BoxEqualityComparer());
```

Теперь при добавлении в эту коллекцию объекта типа `Box` дубликат не добавится.

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативное решение — использовать `IEquatable<Obj>`, если у вас понятие равенства всё время одинаковое.

```
class Obj : IEquatable<Obj>
{
    readonly int A1, A2, A3;

    public Obj(int a1, int a2, int a3)
    {
        A1 = a1; A2 = a2; A3 = a3;
    }

    // определяем сравнение
    public bool Equals(Obj that)
    {
        return that != null && this.A1 == that.A1 && this.A2 == that.A2;
    }

    // заодно нужно перегрузить унаследованное сравнение
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Obj);
    }

    // при этом обязательно перегрузить GetHashCode
    // мы должны убедиться, что равные по Equals экземпляры имеют одинаковый хэшкод
    // поэтому в вычислениях участвует только A1 и A2
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = 19;
        // избегаем хэш-коллизий, используем (небольшое) простое число
        hash = hash * 37 + A1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 37 + A2.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    // чтобы увидеть результат
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"a1 = {A1}, a2 = {A2}, a3 = {A3}";
    }
}
```

Ну и тестируем. В качестве контейнера без дубликатов берём `HashSet<Obj>`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objects = new HashSet<Obj>();
        objects.Add(new Obj(1, 1, 10));
        objects.Add(new Obj(1, 1, 100));
        foreach (var obj in objects)
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

В выводе лишь один экземпляр, как и нужно:

> a1 = 1, a2 = 1, a3 = 10

---

Если понятие равенства у вас «ситуативное», важное только для этого контейнера, лучше использовать идею с `IEqualityComparer<Obj>`.