# Удаление дубликатов из массива по условию

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив объектов со свойствами ResolvedFile и AssetFileName.
Оба свойства это пути к файлу, причем могут быть записаны в достаточно бредовом  виде - например C:\SomePath/\///abc.jpg и C:/SomePath///abc.JPG.
в методе IsPathEquals(string path1, string path2) эти пути нормализуются и сравниваются.

Вот медленный метод получения уникальной коллекции.

```
    var uniqueAssets = new List<AssetItem>();
    foreach (var item in usedFiles)
    {
        if (uniqueAssets.Any(uniqueItem => AssetPath.IsPathEquals(uniqueItem.ResolvedFile, item.ResolvedFile) && AssetPath.IsPathEquals(uniqueItem.AssetFileName, item.AssetFileName)))
            continue;
        uniqueAssets.Add(item);
    }
```

Есть такой замечательный быстрый метод от легендарного Джона Скит, но что-то не соображу как к нему прикрутить мою проверку.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/489421/2237301

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: так а что надо проверить? что пара из двух свойств уникальна?

Comment: на выбор дубликат: [раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536940/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/536942#536942), [два](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510535#511995)

Comment: Спасибо - то, что нужно!